# Double derivative w.r.t x and y needed

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

I have the following function $$h(x,y)=\int_{\frac{eaf}{c(1-x)}}^\infty e^{-t-\frac{eagf}{cx(1-y)t}}dt$$

where $a,c,e,f,g$ are constants. I need to find the double derivative w.r.t. $x$ and $y$ i.e. $\frac{\partial^2h}{\partial x^2}$ and $\frac{\partial^2h}{\partial y^2}$. I know that Leibniz theorem can be used for differentiation of function that involve integrals however I do not know how it will apply in the present situation.

Comment: http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~jyang06/stat411/handouts/InterchangeDiffandIntegral.pdf To see interchange of differentiation and integral. However, if you apply this then try to find derivative of integrand wrt. x and y.

Comment: You might wanna rename your function, or the constant $f$ to some other name to avoid confusion.

Comment: @JustinBenfield changes made thank you Justin

Answer (score 1):

Put $eaf/c=:p$. Then its about
$$h(x,y):=\int_{p/(1-x)}^\infty\exp\bigl(-t-pg/(xt(1-y))\bigr)\>dt\ .$$
Leibniz rule  says that for a function
$$f(x):=\int_{a(x)}^b\phi(x,t)\>dt$$
one has (under suitable technical assumptions)
$$f'(x)=-\phi\bigl(a(x),t\bigr)\>a'(x)+\int_{a(x)}^b\phi_x(x,t)\>dt\ ,$$
whereby $\phi_x$ denotes the partial derivative of $\phi$ with respect to its first variable $x$. Using this rule time and again, and similarly with respect to $y$, you'll obtain at the end  terribly complicated expressions, containing free terms as well as integrals, for the desired ${\partial^2h\over\partial x^2}$, ${\partial^2h\over\partial y^2}$.

Comment: I think here $\phi_x(x,t)$ is the derivative of $\phi(x,t)$ w.r.t. $x$. Right?